# How to use outerHtml in Angular 9+?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I used `outerHtml` which ended up with a lot of errors. Can anyone suggest alternative methods for this `angular 9+` project? I have `HTML` content with `JS` external plugins which has been loaded into my `Angular` page
[image: error message]

Comment: How do you get `outerHTML` ? what is the type of that element ? Please add part of code

Answer (score 0):

Any Outer html will be used in the parent ID and Custom PIPE to solve the above error
i have installed **NPM SafeHtml**

```
<div id="BindingelementID"><div [outerHTML]="item.html | safe: 'html' "> </div></div>
```